# Is there a word for referring to yourself in the third person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ed would like to know if there is a word to describe someone who refers to themself in the third person.

Comment: Bob Dole? Donald Trump?

Comment: A Facebook user?

Comment: Bill should have thought to post this here himself.  :)

Comment: Dmckee thinks people who do that are pretentious jerks.

Comment: there are also people talking like that in their daily conversation? In my native language they would sound cute to talk with others that way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ed suggests the word is [illeism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism).

> Ed is an illeist.

Comment: BoltClock agrees.

Comment: splattne upvoted you.

Comment: So perhaps is this commenter, who can't help thinking Ed may have posted this question after reading what looks to me like a somewhat fanciful Wikipedia entry.

Comment: This answer is uninformative and rather lazy given the wealth of readily available and amusing information on *illeism*.

Comment: @z7sg So make it better?

Comment: I think you could get more upvotes if you fleshed this out, but I learned a new word from your answer